# candidate for rigorous _mathematical_ definition of "canonical"?

Tags: lo.logic

In this question: [What is the definition of "canonical"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical)
, people gave interesting "philosophical" takes on what the word "canonical" means. Moreover I percieved an underlying opinion that there was no formal mathematical definition.

Whilst looking for something else entirely, I just ran into Bill Messing's post

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2007-December/012359.html

on the FOM (Foundations of Mathematics) mailing list. I'll just quote the last paragraph:

"It is my impression that there is very little FOM discussion of either
Hilbert's epsilon symbol or of Bourbaki formulation of set theory.  In
particular the chapitre IV Structures of Bourbaki.  For reasons,
altogether mysterious to me, the second edition (1970) of this book
supressed the appendix of the first edition (1958).  This appendix gave
what is, as far as I know, the only rigorous mathematical discussion of
the definition of the word "canonical".  Given the fact that Chevalley
was, early in his career, a close friend of Herbrand and also very
interested in logic, I have guessed that it was Chevalley who was the
author of this appendix.  But I have never asked any of the current or
past members of Bourbaki whom I know whether this is correct."

It's a 4-day weekend here in the UK and I'm very unlikely to get to a library to find out what this suppressed appendix says. Wouldn't surprise me if someone could find this appendix on the web somewhere though! Is there really a *mathematical* definition of "canonical"??

NOTE: if anyone has more "philosophical" definitions of the word, they can put them in the other thread. I am hoping for something different here.

Comment: There was one underlying mathematical definition given in the other thread, which was "functorial."  Is this unsatisfying?

Comment: @Qiaochu: I have in my hand a paper by Nick Katz ("p-adic properties of modular schemes and modular forms") where he says that a certain exact sequence coming from the theory of elliptic curves has a "canonical, but not functorial, splitting" (page Ka-95, a.k.a. p163 of the book).

Comment: In the spirit of the old nonsense about a tree which falls in the forest when nobody is around to hear the noise, if a mathematical concept is defined in a place which is known to almost nobody then the definition may as well not exist.  Or in the words of a US Supreme Court case struggling with another widely used undefined word, as long as we know it when we see it then probably there's no need for a rigorous definition (much like there's no need for rigorous foundations of category theory as long as it is being used in an essentially linguistic or "plug example into machine" manner). 

Comment: Manjul Bhargava got a big laugh in one of his early talks on his higher composition laws. In the difficult degree five case, someone asked if the number field entity Manjul constructed had a certain desirable property, and he replied "No, but it's unique." 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjul_Bhargava  

Comment: Brian: of course you're right. In some sense you're raising the question as to whether one even needs to give a definition. The only thing I was flagging was that Messing was seemingly offering a reference for a mathematical definition, which somehow surprised me. You and I were both in his Paris lecture last week, right? We should have asked him!

Comment: Ps @Brian: do you understand Katz' "canonical but not functorial" statement? I bet my bottom pound that you've thought about it!

Comment: @Kevin: Am in Michigan now, so no access to Katz' stuff; let me then answer by giving unrelated instance: unipotent radical of a smooth connected affine group over an alg. closed field is canonical (in any reasonable sense) but not functorial in the category of all such groups...though functorial with respect to  surjections (not obvious just from definitions!). And orthogonal complement of a closed subspace of a Hilbert space is canonical but not functorial for (bounded) linear maps. Etc. 

Comment: @Brian: The orthogonal complement of a closed subspace of a Hilbert space is canonical and functorial for unitary linear maps that are surjective on the subspace.  Generally speaking, every instance of the word “canonical” implies that you have to choose a right category to obtain functoriality.  I presume that in Katz' example one also needs to choose a different category before the splitting becomes canonical.

Comment: @Dmitri: When writing my comments I had in mind what you say, but we could always go a step further and pass to the discrete subcategory (with only identity morphisms) to make "everything" canonical. :)  So I thought the main interesting feature of those little examples I mentioned was that one can make natural useful constructions whose functoriality is very restricted compared with where we begin (surjections of appropriate sort for the unipotent radical and orthogonal complement examples, etc.)

Comment: Dear Kevin,

I don't have my copy of Katz with me, but his splitting is something
like splitting $H^1_{dR}$ of an elliptic curve as a sum of $H^{0,1}$ and $H^{1,0}$, a splitting which is canonical, but not functorial in the sense that it does not behave well in families.  (The Hodge filtration behaves well in families, but not the Hodge decomposition,
since the $H^{0,1}$ part varies anti-holomorphically, rather than holomorphically.)

Comment: Here's a nice little example. I'd say that the center of a group a canonical construction, but it does not prolong to a functor on the category of groups.

Comment: OK, so, @Qiaochu, the answer to the question you asked above is "no" :-) But somehow it all depends on _how_ functorial you want it, somehow. I wish I understood Francois' answer better.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Suppose C and D are categories. There should be a difference between "there exists a functor from C to D" and "there is a canonical functor from C to D". 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the Bourbaki formulation of set theory is very seldom used in foundations, the existence of a definable Hilbert $\varepsilon$ operator has been well studied by set theorists but under a different name. The hypothesis that there is a definable well-ordering of the universe of sets is denoted V = OD (or V = HOD); this hypothesis is equivalent to the existence of a definable Hilbert $\varepsilon$ operator.

More precisely, an [ordinal definable set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set) is a set $x$ which is the unique solution to a formula $\phi(x,\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is an ordinal parameter. Using the reflection principle and syntactic tricks, one can show that there is a single formula $\theta(x,\alpha)$ such that for every ordinal $\alpha$ there is a unique $x$ satisfying $\theta(x,\alpha)$ and every ordinal definable set is the unique solution of $\theta(x,\alpha)$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. Therefore, the (proper class) function $T$ defined by $T(\alpha) = x$ iff $\theta(x,\alpha)$ enumerates all ordinal definable sets.

The axiom V = OD is the sentence $\forall x \exists \alpha \theta(x,\alpha)$. If this statement is true, then given any formula $\phi(x,y,z,\ldots)$, one can define a Hilbert $\varepsilon$ operator $\varepsilon x \phi(x,y,z,\ldots)$ to be $T(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the first ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\phi(T(\alpha),y,z,\ldots)$ (when there is one).

The statement V = OD is independent of ZFC. It implies the axiom of choice, but the axiom of choice does not imply V = OD; V = OD is implied by the axiom of constructibility V = L.

---

When I wrote the above (which is actually a reply to Messing) I was expecting that Bourbaki would define canonical in terms of their $\tau$ operator (Bourbaki's $\varepsilon$ operator). However, I was happily surprised when reading the 'état 9' that Thomas Sauvaget found, they make the correct observation that $\varepsilon$ operators do not generally give canonical objects.

A term is said to be 'canonically associated' to structures of a given species if (1) it makes no mention of objects other than 'constants' associated to such structures and (2) it is invariant under transport of structure. Thus, in the species of two element fields the terms 0 and 1 are canonically associated to the field F, but $\varepsilon x(x \in F)$ is not since there is no reason to believe that it is invariant under transport of structures. They also remark that $\varepsilon x(x \in F)$ is actually invariant under automorphisms, so the weaker requirement of invariance under automorphisms does not suffice for being canonical.

---

To translate 'canonically associated' in modern terms:

1) This condition amounts to saying that the 'term' is definable without parameters, without any choices involved. (Note that the language is not necessarily first-order.)

2) This amounts to 'functoriality' (in the loose sense) of the term over the [core groupoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core) of the concrete category associated to the given species of structures.

So this seems to capture most of the points brought up in the answers to the [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical).

Comment: Francois: you are telling me precisely the kind of mathematics that I had hoped this question would inspire. I am currently way behind though. I am happy with V=L. Let me try and translate what you say in your second para above. You say "let's well-order everything with <. Now given a non-empty bunch of sets we can take the 'smallest' one (wrt this ordering). Now if F is an arbitrary field of order 2, its 'smallest' element is automorphism-invariant (as Aut(F)=1) but not isomorphism-invariant (as if F and G are fields of order 2, the smallest elt in one might be 0 but in the other might be 1)"

Comment: So that's an example of something not canonical. But if I have enough mathematics to isolate the 0 and 1 of a field, clearly these are canonical---because they're isomorphism-invariant? But all this seems very far away from the statement (which I truly believe) that the isomorphisms of local class field theory (sending a uniformiser to a geometric Frobenius) are canonical. Am I now using canonical in a different way? Can one get from terms and functoriality to local class field theory isomorphisms?

Comment: Kevin, this is correct. The point can be summarized as follows: V = OD gives a canonical way of making choices, but not a way of making canonical choices.

Comment: This is not my specialty so I can't say for sure, but I think sending a uniformizer to the geometric Frobenius is canonical and so is the inverse convention. The Bourbaki language of species is not first-order, so you can talk about a variety of higher-order objects (e.g. idèles and adèles would certainly be canonical) so the fact that there are small variations shouldn't affect things very much.

Comment: @Francois: class field theory isn't hard to summarise. Let me try and abstractify the number theory away. I have a fixed field Q_p. If F is any finite extension of Q_p then I can associate two topological groups canonically to F: call them Wab(F) [the abelianisation of the Weil group associated to F] and M(F) [the multiplicative group F^*]. Now Wab() and M() can be extended to covariant functors from the cat of finite extensions of Q_p (with the morphisms being inclusions) to the cat of topological groups, and they can also be extended to contravariant functors between these categories!

Comment: [e.g. if F1 is contained in F2 then the map M(F2)-->M(F1) is just the norm map of fields]. I now fix a Frobenius convention once and for all: "geometric Frobenius will go to a uniformiser". Once I have done this, the main theorem of local class field theory is an isomorphism Wab(F)=M(F) for each field F, which extends to an isomorphism of covariant functors and an isomorphism of contravariant functors. Do you have enough information to be able to say either that this identification Wab(F)=M(F) is canonical, or to identify what further needs to be checked in order to see if it's canonical?

Comment: More importantly: does this have anything to do with this Bourbaki appendix! _That_ is what I'm trying to establish!

Comment: The way I understand Bourbaki and your situation, I believe that your construction is canonical, up to an epsilon doubt. Condition (2) should be fine. For (1), the only difficulty I see is when you say the Frobenius goes to *a* uniformizer, you're implicitly choosing a uniformizer, but probably this doesn't matter much in this case?

Comment: "you're implicitly choosing a uniformizer", no, don't worry, I'm not. Geometric Frobenius is precisely as ambiguously-defined as uniformiser. It's either the case that every geom frob goes to a uniformiser (and every uniformiser is hit by a geom frob), or every geom frob goes to the inverse of a uniformiser. The convention just says which of the two canonical isomorphisms you're using---nothing more. Finally I should say that if you're saying "I said all this earlier" then I have to confess that I must have not appreciated the force of what you were saying earlier. Apologies.

Comment: (It's been years since I looked at local CFT, so I didn't want to say anything too silly, which is why I was vague earlier.) I still have a half-epsilon of doubt. It sounds like the uniformizer-Frobenius correspondence is still not uniquely determined. If I have a specific uniformizer p, do I still have a choice of which geometric Frobenius I send it to? Sounds like if I pick one then I get all the rest for free, but I'm not sure whether I have an obvious choice for the first. (I'm sure this doesn't matter at all in practice, but I'm trying to apply Bourbaki by the book here.)

Comment: "If I have a specific uniformizer p, do I still have a choice of which geometric Frobenius I sent it to?". *No*. Note that for most local fields, p is ramified, so p isn't a uniformiser. For Q_p there is a canonical uniformiser, but there's also a canonical Frobenius---the one which is trivial on the cyclotomic extension, the point being that the cyclotomic extension generates all the inertia group. I have misled you with this "geom frob = uniformiser" statement. All I am doing is choosing a left shoe over a right shoe---there are no more choices involved.

Comment: OK. I was worried unit factors could have a more serious impact. Sounds like Bourbaki would say this is canonical, provided you say which convention you use, otherwise Bourbaki might not know exactly which 'term' you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

There are scanned notes in french that were used for the initial text of *Théorie des Ensembles* [on the Bourkaki Archives website](http://mathdoc.emath.fr/archives-bourbaki/feuilleter.php?chap=2_REDAC_E1).

In particular there are indeed notes by Chevalley named *Livre I. Théorie des ensembles Chap. IV (état 7 ?) Structures (53 p.)* which seem at first glance to define "canonique" in the broader context of "transport de structures, idendifications" (see exemple 1 at the bottom of page 19 of that file).

Comment: That's a very interesting website! I'm not convinced that the reference you give is what Messing is referring to though. It seems to me that they are just giving some standard examples of canonical isomorphisms (e.g. "the integers" (however they have defined them) are canonically isomorphic to the subset of the rationals consisting of things which are integers...)

Comment: You're right. I had another look and I think the relevant file is the last one (état 9), which does have an appendix, as Messing mnetions, in which at page 37 and 38 we find: "un terme U est canoniquement associé à la structure générique $(s_1,...,s_p)$" to be defined as "U ne contient aucune lettre autre que les constantes de $T_\Sigma$ et est transportable relativement à $\Sigma$".  It is also given the alternative name "intrinsèque pour $(s_1,...,s_p)$".

Comment: You could well be right about \'etat 9. At first glance---I can't make head nor tail of it! I wonder what it says!